# IE8 text-indent and placeholder issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

[image]

I have two problems here:

1) Place holder

2) Cursor text indent

First, I googled a bit, and know that the placeholder is a HTML5 feature and isn't support in IE8.  Is there an alternate solution?

Second, in IE8, the cursor doesn't start with text indent.

HTML:

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" id="home_email_input" name="username" placeholder="E-mail" type="text">
<input id="home_pw_input" name="password" placeholder="PW" type="password">
```

CSS:

```
#home_email_input {
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 183px;
    background: url(/images/envelope.gif) no-repeat scroll 4px 3px;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
#home_pw_input {
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 183px;
    background: url(/images/lock.gif) no-repeat 5px -0.5px;
    text-indent: 30px;
}
```

Comment: http://andrew-jones.com/jquery-placeholder-plugin/

Comment: Google: `placeholder plugin`

Comment: use placeholder.js which avoids placeholder problem in ie8 and below

Comment: for text-indent, you can use left padding

Comment: There are [lots of placeholder scripts](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder) that you could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `line-height` to get the indent work for `IE`

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/Cernx/12/

For the placeholder, you must use `javascript`. There is not other alternative in `HTML`.

Comment: i have a icon inside the input field, and cuz of this, if i add line-height it changes weird :(

Comment: What changes? The position? Use center `background: url(/images/envelope.gif) no-repeat scroll 4px center;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [webshims](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/) library to shim the placeholders in

For the text indent, just add extra left padding to the input box for IE

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution is to have labels for the input fields, instead of using placeholder as an unreliable surrogate for a label. The placeholder is supposed to help the user e.g. with a description of the expected input format, not to do the job of a label. Example:

```
<label for=email>E-mail:</label> <input type=email id=email name=email>
```

The HTML5 CR says about the [`placeholder` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute): “The placeholder attribute should not be used as a replacement for a label. [...] Use of the placeholder attribute as a replacement for a label can reduce the accessibility and usability of the control for a range of users including older users and users with cognitive, mobility, fine motor skill or vision impairments. While the hint given by the control's label is shown at all times, the short hint given in the placeholder attribute is only shown before the user enters a value. Furthermore, placeholder text may be mistaken for a pre-filled value, and as commonly implemented the default color of the placeholder text provides insufficient contrast and the lack of a separate visible label reduces the size of the hit region available for setting focus on the control.”